# how to install wayback 1.4.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am new to Ubuntu,

so I don't know how to install wayback...

I downloaded `wayback-1.4.2.tar.gz` from some website...

next what will I do...

anyone explain..

Comment: What the heck is wayback1.4.2?! (Seriously, never heard about it. Please post more information about it, at least an official website.) | Also which Ubuntu? Architecture? ...

Comment: Wayback is a versioning filesystem in userspace. http://wayback.sourceforge.net/ is the only address I could find, but they list 1.0.1 as the most resent release (in 2004).

Comment: If that is the case then the OP needs to define which tool he is after as he may have downloaded something completely unrelated and useless to them. The name seems to be shared between your versioning filesystem http://wayback.sourceforge.net/ and a website archiver http://archive-access.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find is:

> I believe this page has the install instructions
>
> http://archive-access.sourceforge.net/projects/wayback/administrator_manual.html

The instructions look pretty comprehensive, but I suspect that Wayback is an application that lacks a graphical user interface and as a side effect also lacks an easy method of installation.  Take the UI out of a Linux program and what you tend to end up with is a very steep learning curve to figure out what you need to do to make the thing work.

Why specifically do you need Wayback?  Would something like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) do?  I would expect HTTrack to be in the Ubuntu repository...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the exact version you were looking for to install, but the instructions on [Wayback's Sourceforge page](http://wayback.sourceforge.net/) tell that it's the normal *make*, *make install* routine that's required to install Wayback.

So, first you should obtain the source for your current kernel, then issue the following commands in the untarred Wayback directory:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Also, make sure that the first step is successfull before trying the installing.